# How to access resolved state dependency directly from the template, without creating a controller?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Here's a resolved Object.

```
resolve: {
    Temp: function() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Now If I create a controller for this state, Then I can inject this `Temp` dependency and use this object in the Template/View through $scope by doing this.

```
function TempController($scope,Temp){
    $scope.temp = Temp
}
```

This is the only use of `tempController`. If there's a way around without creating this controller, then it would be a great performance boost.

So the question comes, In general, how to access this resolved dependency (`Temp`) from the template/View `temp.html` without creating a controller?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into ui-router **components**, I don't know much about them, but here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756508/provide-ui-router-resolved-resources-without-injecting-directly-into-controller)

Comment: Seems like it can do the trick. I'm gonna check into it. Thanks